# Android fragments show exit animation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have to create an activity with about 6 fragments, an important requirement is for the fragmets to animate in one direction and animate backward the same direction they came in, I have been able to find a solution that will animate the enter animation, but the exit animation never runs, any help will go a long way thanks!

Activity

```
public class HomeFragmentActivity extends Activity {

Fragment fr;

Integer pagePosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_fragment);

    pagePosition = 0;

}


public void categoryNavClick(View view) {


        fr = new FragmentOne();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_right_anim, R.anim.enter_right_anim);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frHomeFragment, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        pagePosition = 0;



}

public void homeNavClick(View view) {

        fr = new FragmentTwo();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_right_anim, R.anim.exit_right_anim);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frHomeFragment, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        pagePosition = 1;

}
```

}

enter_right_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-2000"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

exit_right_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="2000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a view pager along with a tab layout,both are part of the app compat library and do alot of the grunt work for you including animating fragments and swiping fragments and can also be backported to older android versions.

Comment: Unfortunately the other views cant be shown when moving from one view to the next, what the client wants is a navigation similar to what instagram does on their app

Answer (score 0):

you have the same animation in the entry and exit in the set custom animation

try to put an offset too in the entering of the fragment, then it will only apear after the first one leave, like the requirement you told about 
"the other views cant be shown when moving from one view to the next, what the client wants"

---

update

The exiting view is animated on the canvas of the entering view, so you create the animation like you have, but the entering animation try to put

```
android:startOffset="1000"
```

one thousand offset because its 1 second animation to the other fragment to disappear

the other thing was this line

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_right_anim, R.anim.enter_right_anim);
```

it has the same animation to enter and leave

Comment: This is the first time I've had to create this type of layout so I am a bit confused by the answer, would you be able to show a basic code example?